# Why can't I login using three user levels?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm creating three user levels for application needs.
Here are the user levels I created:

> **admin**, **user**, and **viewer**

I have grouped the pages that can be accessed when logged in via **web.php** with the following code:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','checklevel:admin']], function(){
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','checklevel:user']], function(){
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','checklevel:viewer']], function(){
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
});
```

With the order of the group above, only the viewer level can log in, but if the admin level group is at the bottom, only the admin level can log in unless the user level still cannot log in even though the user group is at the bottom.

Below is checklevel.php to support a more detailed analysis of fixing this problem:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckLevel
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$levels)
    {
        if (in_array($request->user()->level,$levels)){
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you identify the user? Can you show your checklevel middleware code?. Also the last routes will override the previous routes unless there is a prefix that is different for all routes

Comment: You have defined only one GET route named `dashboard` with URL `/dashboard`, in the last group closure. You can redefine the same route over and over but only the last one works. VTC as typo.

Comment: 1. When you say `logged in` do you mean open the dashboard? 2. Do you wish for all 3 types of users to open `dashboard` when logged in?

Comment: Yes, when logged in, they open the dashboard. @Mr.Kenneth

Comment: I just put checklevel.php please check it, so what do I have to do? @SaineshMamgain

Comment: Yes, it's true that only the last group route works, but when the group route is at the user level and I put it on last, it still doesn't get in. So the admin and viewer-level groups can log in when I put it at the very end. @miken32

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer to the best that I can.

The code provided in the question will **only** allow users that was declared in `'checklevel:〇〇'` where `〇〇` is the level name.

If you wish to allow all 3 (but maybe you have 5 levels) you can do the following:

web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','checklevel:admin|user|viewer']], function(){
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
});
```

Checklevel.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $permissionList)
{
    $level = explode('|', $permissionList); // change 'admin|user|viewer' to array
    if (in_array($request->user()->level, $level)){
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect('/');
}
```

You will need to update your CheckLevel code based on your needs but this should be a start.

Comment: I have tried deleting two groups and only leaving one group. In fact, the three users couldn't log in, the admin level returned to the welcome page, the user level remained on the login page, and the viewer level returned to the welcome page.

Comment: Did you try the `Route` that I provided? inside `handle()` what is the value of `$permissionList` before and after explode?

Comment: in your earleir comment, this is because only the `viewer` level was allowed in the middleware. did you try to add the three level just like in my answer? separated by a pipe ?